# How does stylesheets work in Qt?

Tags: windows, qt

It is just curiosity. In Windows, for instance, how Qt interprets the stylesheets? this seems to be trivial, but, how does Qt tells the operating system to change the appearance of the widgets? Which library of methods of the Windows API uses? Does WPF uses the same Windows API libraries?

Cheers,

Comment: I believe Qt directly draws the widgets to emulate the native look on each system it supports so it would not be using a windows api to handle the style.

Comment: Are you really sure? It seems to be calling Windows API since most of the controls are exactly the same, for instance QPushButton 'blue' effect in Windows 7...

Comment: Just dig into the Qt source. You'll see your QWidgets only have an HWND if you specify explicitly. You can't have a Win32 button without an HWND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt custom draws all widgets. Qt may, under the hood, call into to OS provided API's for rendering each widget but a QButton is not an HWND using the BUTTON window class on windows. Qt does seem to use the OS for rendering text on the widgets but only the glyphs, not the complex rendering available in QLabel for example.